# User edit url for profile

Tags: 7

I have create menu link named as my account

Now i want to link that my account link to  user/user_id(currnt login user)/edit

Anybody  tell me how to do that

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This looks like something that you could use the **[Menu token](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token)** module for. Install and enable the module, then use a link path like this:
`user/[current-user:uid]/edit`

[image]